# Vuejs show product page in combination with repeatable route params as nested categories

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I would like to access a product details page within the set of categories.
For example: `website.com/catalog/cat1/cat2/cat3/product-item-123`

I'm using a [Repeatable params](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/route-matching-syntax.html#repeatable-params) to construct a nested set of categories, so URL would look like this which works fine:
`website.com/catalog/category/subcategory/anothersubcateg/`

```
{
  path: '/catalog/:slug+',
  name: 'category.show',
  component: () => import('pages/category.show.vue'),
  props: route => ({ slug: route.params.slug })
},
```

But when I add a new route rule it overrides all pages for categories and shows a product page instead:

```
{
  path: '/catalog/:slug+/:productSlug',
  name: 'product.show',
  component: () => import('pages/product.show.vue'),
  props: route => ({ slug: route.params.slug })
}
```

How to render a `pages/product.show.vue` file only when the product page is opened and not override the `pages/category.show.vue` file ?

**UPDATED**

Here is the list of URLs I would like to have:

```
format: /CAT+/PRODUCT_ID-PRODUCT_SLUG
/clothes/t-shirts/winter/men/20380-underarmor-crossfit-99x
/hardware/gpus/87689-nvidia-rtx-3080ti-24gb
/smartphones/ios/iphone-13-pro-512gb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you cannot use regex to help you sort products from categories, the simplest solution seems to be to add a separator section to your url to tell the router that what follows is a product:

```
  path: '/catalog/:slug+/product/:productSlug',
```

Tell me if you're still facing an issue. Happy coding!

Comment: `product-item` should be a name of product in url form type, for example: `surface-studio-2-32gb`. I tried `'/catalog/:slug(\\w+)+/:productSlug(\\d+)',` but it does not work

Comment: `\\d+` here means 'one or more digits', so if your products id are random strings that makes it harder to make the patterns match, although it might still be possible. Could you edit your question by adding more samples of what your categories and products name look like so I can help you to find a right regex please?

Comment: I've updated the question, please check after the "UPDATE" title. Also I thought to make a matching possible, I would use `product_id` number  following with a dash `-` and `product_slug` like so: `888-someproductnameslug`